# Determine whether $V_{T_1}$ and $V_{T_2}$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}[t]$-modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, solution-verification, free-modules

Given a two-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-module, $V$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$, define two $\mathbb{Q}[t]$-module structures as follows:
$$T_1:= \begin{cases} 
      te_1 \mapsto e_2\\
      te_2 \mapsto e_1 \\
   \end{cases} $$
$$ T_2:=\begin{cases} 
      te_1 \mapsto e_2\\
      te_2 \mapsto e_1+e_2 \\
   \end{cases} $$
Attempt: I claim $V_{T_2}$ and $V_{T_2}$ are not isomorphic. Isomorphism classes of $k[t]$ modules are in a one-to-one correspondence with similarity classes of the underlying matrix representations of the endomorphism that gives a $k$-vector space its $k[t]$-module structure. Consider the two matrices representing the two $k[t]$-modules,
$$M_{T_1}=A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_{T_2}=B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
The corresponding characteristic polynomials are $P_A(t)=t^2-1$ and $P_B(t)=t^2-t-1$, note that this implies that $A$ has two eigenvalues while $B$ has no eigenvalues. Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues $\implies A$ and $B$ are not similar, $\implies V_{T_1} \not\cong V_{T_2}$ as $\mathbb{Q}[t]$-modules.

I wanted to check if this reasoning works, because on my final last semester I was told to be careful about using the characteristic polynomial. I made a statement along the lines of, "They have different characteristic polynomials therefore they're not similar" which I was shown wasn't necessarily true. But does this eigenvalue argument work? My linear algebra really needs work before my algebra qualifier coming up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two matrices with different characteristic polynomials cannot be similar. Indeed, $\det(A - xI) = \det(QAQ^{-1} - x I)$ for any $Q$, since $QAQ^{-1} - x I = Q(A - x I)Q^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok so its just if I was trying to prove similarity that an issue would come up? Like if I was claiming that they were isomorphic I would need more than just that they have the same characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Yeah. Having the same characteristic polynomial doesn't force similarity, but your proof from the question was fine.